# Given a biased coin, find to which side it is biased.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have a biased coin, but don't know which side *(heads or tails)* is more probable. What sort of an algorithm could determine towards which side the coin is biased? Moreover, how can the error of such an algorithm be evaluated? The error is the probability of the algorithm's prediction being wrong, obviously.

To simplify the task, the algorithm does not have to terminate, but the mean amount of coin flips should be finite nonetheless.

Comment: Do we have any idea how biased? might the probabilities be $0.5000001$ and $0.4999999$ or even tighter?

Comment: You can use that $B(n,p) \sim N(np, np(1-p))$ for large $n$. The error is proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{np}}$ if $0<p\leq 1/2$.

Comment: @Henry It can be tight, the only restrictions are $1>p>0.5$.

Comment: @Dayton I am aware of this approximation, but I do not follow how this helps to find $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assign numerical values to tails (=0) and heads (=1). Let as assume that the heads have probability $p$ to come up.

The result of a toss is a random variable $X$, with the expected value $$\mathbb{E}X = p\cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot 0 = p$$ and variance $$\sigma^2 = \mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)^2 = p \cdot(1-p)^2 + (1-p)\cdot p^2 = p(1-p)$$ $N$ tosses of a coin will be represented by $N$ independent variables $X_n$. Let us define
$$ \overline X = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n}X_n$$
we have
$$ \mathbb{E}\overline X = p$$
$$ \mathbb{E}(\overline X^2) = p^2 + \frac{p(1-p)}{N}$$
$$ \mathbb{E}\overline (\overline X - \overline X^2) = p(1-p)(1-\frac{1}{N})$$
$$ \mathbb{E}((\overline X - p)^2) = \frac{p(1-p)}{N} = \frac{1}{N-1}\mathbb{E} (\overline X - \overline X^2)$$
That means that if you perform $N$ coin tosses then calculating $\overline X$ will give you the estimation of the probability $p$, and calculating $\frac{\overline X - \overline X^2}{N-1} $ will give you the estimation of how accurate this estimation of $p$ is. This accuracy is expected to grow with $N$.